# C# edit button to Access database

Tags: c#, sql, prepared-statement

I have a particular part of an inventory interface that requires an employee to select his or her name from a combo box and then scan a product to the table assigned to the name of the employee.

My curiosity is: When hitting the `EDIT`, `ADD` OR `DELETE` button it knows what table to perform this function in from a *Switch - Case* statement with that employee name on it. The problem is, the piece of code is long for each employee, especially for 9 employees that each have a *Switch - Case* statement.

Any advice on how to simplify this or shorten the code? I do understand in advance about the *parameterized SQL* that I am failing to use. Just trying to accomplish this first.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveControl = txtSerialN;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSerialN.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cboEmpName.Text))

            switch (cboEmpName.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim())
            {
                case "John Doe":
                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                        command.Connection = connection;

                        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO JohnDoe(SerialNumber,PartNumber,DateEntered,Customer) values ('" + txtSerialN.Text + "','" + txtPart.Text + "','" + txtDate.Text + "','" + txtCustomer.Text + "')";
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("Inventory Added".PadLeft(23));

                        connection.Close();
                        txtSerialN.Clear();
                        txtPart.Clear();
                        txtDate.Clear();
                        txtCustomer.Clear();

                        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM JohnDoe ORDER BY PartNumber";
                        OleDbDataAdapter db = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        db.Fill(dt);
                        dataGridEmpParts.DataSource = dt;
                    }

                    catch (OleDbException)
                    {
                        string strmsg = "THIS SERIAL NUMBER ALREADY EXISTS ! , Please try again";
                        MessageBox.Show(strmsg, "YOU CAN'T ENTER THE SAME ONE AGAIN", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                    break;
            }
    }
```

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: Yes.....I know. This is a local Interface used by 9 people that have no interest in trying to hack the Interface.

Comment: please verify me your actual problem is that ?        "The problem is, the piece of code is long for each employee, especially for 9 employees that each have a Switch - Case statement. "

Comment: you means more the number of employee more will be switch statement

Answer (score 1):

I would rather put up a lookup table that will have columns such as EmployeeName,  AssignedTable and dynamically construct the commandtext based on the parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this problem could more efficiently be fixed by altering the database. Perhaps even as simple as adding a field for employee name.